# Sklearn PCA projection differences while reproducing projection sample by sample

Tags: pca, scikit-learn, numpy

I've been stuck on this issue due to inability to reproduce the performance of PCA-classification pipeline on training data, but in case the pipeline receives one sample at a time. This seems to be floating point arithmetic issue.

1. Using sklearn I fit the PCA model to the matrix data:

   pca.fit(X_) - shape of X_ is (109,400), the model has 10 components

   Z = pca.transform(X_)
2. I calculate the difference between recalculate the Z using fitted coefficients:

   ```
   x_ = X_ - pca.mean_
   X_transformed = np.dot(x_, pca.components_.T)
   sum(Z - X_transformed)

   last line of course returns 0.0
   ```
3. Using the same coefficients I project single sample from the X_ matrix

   ```
   x_ = X_[0:1] - pca.mean_
   x_transformed = np.dot(x_, pca.components_.T)
   Z[0:1] - x_transformed

   the result error vector
   array([[ 2.22044605e-16, -8.88178420e-16,  1.94289029e-16,
           -1.77635684e-15, -1.11022302e-16,  4.44089210e-16,
            2.22044605e-16,  4.44089210e-16, -4.44089210e-16,
            1.11022302e-16]])
   ```

- It seems to me that this must be a floating point arithmetic issue i.e. the numerical representation of a number is a e-16 precision number rounded to a different place after coma in each case.*
- I don't understand why it behaves that way and how can I make sure those differences are always 0 (rounding those numbers on some level will only work once I understand the problem).

Please help.

Edit:
The errors seem too small to care, but there is no guarantee that errors won't be magnified in specific case to bring bad result.

Comment: Please describe the "error" you see: why, exactly, is this output erroneous or "unstable"?  These differences are indistinguishable from zeros for the precision inherent in the calculations you are doing.

Comment: “there is no guarantee that errors won't be magnified in specific case to bring bad result.” Well, there are some guarantees like the IEEE 754 floating point standard, which places bounds on the allowable error. Still, an exact reproduction would require using the exact same commands on the exact same hardware—floating-point math isn’t even commutative, and people have gotten by for decades with it. The worry about those tiny differences exploding seems like a bogeyman that doesn’t exist, unless you’re doing something horribly ill-conditioned in the first place.